# Cannot read property 'use' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

in server.js

```
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');

function doFirst(request, response, next) {
    console.log('bacon');
    next();
}

function doSecond(request, response, next) {
    console.log('tuna');
    next();
}
app.use(doFirst);
app.use(doSecond);

var app = connect();
http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```

after running it says cannot read property 'use', i already installed package connect, and already initialize the app also
can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 6):

You should first declare the `app`:

```
var app = connect();
```

and then call the `use` method.

```
app.use(doFirst);
app.use(doSecond);
```